# Sending multiple parameters in @Body with Retrofit2 in Android

Tags: android, retrofit2

I want to send multiple parameters in the Body when i do my Put-call. But Retrofit does not allow me to use the @Body annotation twice in the same method. 
This is how it looks:

```
@PUT("/applicant/{id}")
Call<Integer> sendAnswers(@Path("id")int id, @Body String s_id, @Body List<Integer> listOfAnswers);
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a pojo :

```
public class Answer {
    private String s_id;
    private List<Integer> listOfAnswers;

    public String getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }

    public void setS_id(String s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }

    public List<Integer> getListOfAnswers() {
        return listOfAnswers;
    }

    public void setListOfAnswers(List<Integer> listOfAnswers) {
        this.listOfAnswers = listOfAnswers;
    }
}
```

then set it as body:

```
@PUT("/applicant/{id}")
Call<Integer> sendAnswers(@Path("id")int id, @Body Answer answer);
```